# row number in ForEach using another view for row item

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Let's say I have a simple list with ForEach and numbered rows. Like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 100) { number in
                Text("Row \(number)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What if I want to extract the row to another view:

```
struct ExtractedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row \(number)")
    }
}
```

And in original list change

```
Text("Row \(number)")
```

to be:

```
ExtractedView()
```

How to make numbered rows now? How to pass number to ExtractedView? Because right now I am getting an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'number'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a variable in your `ExtractedView` and pass this number into it:

```swift
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 100) { number in
                ExtractedView(number: number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Row \(number)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Александр! Worked great! :) I only had a problem with a preview for ExtractedView. I changed it to:

`struct ExtractedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var example = 27
 
    static var previews: some View {
  ExtractedView(number: example)
    }
}`

Is it correct or not? :)

Comment: Oh, I guess it can be fixed easier:
`struct ExtractedView_Previews: PreviewProvider { static var previews: some View { ExtractedView(number: 27) } }`

Comment: @mallow, both examples for previews work. another solution with ```Bool``` variable, you can use ```.constant(true)```

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much for your time :)